# Are 'yesterday' and 'now' forms of the same lexeme?

Tags: morphology, lexemes

Is *yesterday* just the past tense form of *now*? Or are they different lexemes entirely?

Comment: Your hypothesis really makes me want to ask the question "what do you think *today* is then?".

Comment: I was inclined to parallel _today_ and _yesterday_. Although, still consider them different lexemes as nouns do not inflect for tense. Someone in my class was arguing the above hypothesis and I figured the best way to back up my counterargument was with the help of people who knew much more than me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In English, only verbs have a past tense but the other parts of speech (nouns, adjectives, adverbs, ...) don't have one. The fact that you can express a notion of past-ness for some of them (e.g., *former president* or *ex-wife*) does not form a past tense.

Also *now* and *yesterday* aren't derivations from a common stem. While using common stems (or recognisably related stems) is not strictly necessary for a past tense (think of the past tense of the verb *to be*) it helps to have some morphological rules for forming a lot of past tense forms.

Together with the semantic arguments formulated by @curiousdannii there is no reason to think of *now* and *yesterday* as one lexeme.

Answer (score 5):

1. *Now* can be analysed as a pro-preposition, a word standing in for a prepositional phrase. It isn't verbal, so the category of tense doesn't apply to it.
2. *Now* and *yesterday* are not parallel terms. *Yesterday* can refer to a whole day, but *now* doesn't even refer to a moment just before now. There's no reason to think that they're the same lexeme.

Comment: *Yesterday* doesn't refer to even a moment before yesterday.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that *now* doesn't refer to a day. It could be  conceived of as an instant or an eon. (Having said that, *yesterday* doesn't always refer to a day either.)

Comment: Right. I meant that *yesterday* refers to a time within a one day period, as does *today*, but not *now*.